# malloc realloc has not been declared

Tags: c++

Project at [libmemcached](https://github.com/Metaswitch/libmemcached-upstream/tree/c1c30b89a80f7f20e5a79dd85ac84ef482c95d3e), I am using CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708. I checked file cstdlib line 151, 164, they should be in C++ standard lib. And `malloc and realloc has not been declared` confuses me.

```
$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/libmemcached'
  CXX      libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/stdlib.h:36,
                 from ./libhashkit/common.h:45,
                 from libhashkit/aes.cc:38:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:151:11: error: '::malloc' has not been declared
  151 |   using ::malloc;
      |           ^~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:164:11: error: '::realloc' has not been declared
  164 |   using ::realloc;
      |           ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./libhashkit/common.h:45,
                 from libhashkit/aes.cc:38:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/stdlib.h:65:12: error: 'std::malloc' has not been declared
   65 | using std::malloc;
      |            ^~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/stdlib.h:73:12: error: 'std::realloc' has not been declared
   73 | using std::realloc;
      |            ^~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/libmemcached'
```

Information about gcc I used:

```
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-9.3.1-20200408/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --disable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2) (GCC)
```

EDIT: After tried deparately, I found that `AC_FUNC_MALLOC` in configure.ac causes this error. Have it removed, and the error is gone. Here is the reason:
[::malloc has not been declared](https://nerdland.net/unstumping-the-internet/malloc-has-not-been-declared/#rootcause)

Comment: @S.M. But I am using CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708. What should I say?

Comment: @S.M. /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/ is the location of the official devtoolset packages from Red Hat, it's basically newer versions of the toolchains than the one shipped with the base installation